# редирект с переменной

Tags: .htaccess, opencart, редирект

Имеется ссылка вида

```
site.ru/omsk/index.php?route=product/search&search=переменная
```

нужно ее перенаправлять на

```
site.ru/index.php?route=product/search&search=переменная
```

что прописать в htaccess для такого редиректа? cms opencart

Answer (score 0):

Флаг `QSA` отвечает за добавление строки параметров

```
RewriteRule ^omsk/index.php$ index.php [L,QSA]
```